# How to enable badge CSS classes in Vaadin 14.7.x when not using custom theme?

Tags: vaadin-flow, vaadin14

From the documentation:

> The Badge-specific CSS classes are available as part of the Lumo
> theme. To use these classes in your application, enable them in your
> theme’s theme.json

And [Lumo Badges](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/lumo/badges) describes how:

```
@JsModule("@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/badge.js") 
// Here, we add the style sheet to   the global scope 
@CssImport(include = "lumo-badge")
```

However, this does not work (`CssImport` also requires a `value`). What should this value be? Where can i find these ccs-files in my Vaadin project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easies way is to use [Badge add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/badge) from the Directory. It gives you easy to use Java API for Lumo badges. You can also look via links the GitHub repo how it has been implemented.

Comment: Okay, the add-on is just an (nice) type safe wrapper for the functionality already part of 14.7 (should be part of vaadin flow imho). But looking at your code, i see what did the trick. A reference is made to an empty css file! The second part of the question is still open: Where can i find the lumo ccs-files in my Vaadin project?

Comment: "Where can i find the lumo ccs-files in my Vaadin project", they are part of the lumo package, you should not have need to directly reference them.